# How to get an outline border on a colgroup?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table with 17 columns, divided into 3 column groups.  I can set the background colour using CSS, which suggests that my CSS selectors are fine.  I can't, however, set a border around the outside of each colgroup.

First I tried this CSS:

```
colgroup.inbound, colgroup.outbound {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And defined column groups this way:

```
<colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
<colgroup span="12" class="inbound"></colgroup>
<colgroup span="3" class="outbound"></colgroup>
```

Next I tried this CSS:

```
col.inbound, col.outbound {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And defined the groups this way:

```
<colgroup
    <col span="2">
    <col span="12" class="inbound">
    <col span="3" class="outbound">            
</colgroup>
```

In both cases my background colour takes effect, but not my border.  The only border I can see is a thin white line between all cells (not around the group as a whole).

I am aware of the table `rules` attribute however I would prefer not to use this.  I think CSS will give me more flexibility, if I can work out how to use it!

Comment: Can you show us the entire table, or an example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to make borders working when using tables you should set the following rule to the table

```
table.collapsed{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

The you will get your border as you pretend

[image]

```
col.inbound, col.outbound {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

A simple example in this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ubapih/4/edit)

**Option**
A border for the whole group instead of for each of the columns

[image]

Then you should rule the colgroup instead of the cols as so..

```
colgroup.inbound  {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

remember allways to use the border-collapse!
This can be seen at this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ubofen/3/edit)

Comment: I cannot get your example to work for just the outside borders. Setting it on the colgroup renders the exact same thing. What am I missing?

Comment: Your solution replaces one problem with another: loss of round table corners. Quoting [6314667](/a/628358/6314667): “`border-radius` does not apply to table elements when the value of  `border-collapse` is `collapse`.”